# KonvaJs - Shape.FillPatternImage not scalled on firefox

Tags: firefox, canvas, png, konvajs

I have a shape rendered in with Konva, when set a fillPatternImage, this one is well rendered with Chrome and stretched with firefox.
[Good rendering in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJNDf.png*)
[False rendering in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fnIq.png)*

The image file is a *.png.
Have somebody any reason why ?

**MORE INFORMATIONS :**

In the following code element is Konva.Rect() object, I set an image for filling in center of the element :

```
  const imageObj = new Image();
  const filename = zone.visual;
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    element.fillPatternImage(imageObj);
    element.fillPatternRepeat('no-repeat');
    element.fillPatternOffsetX((imageObj.width - zone.sizeX) / 2);
    element.fillPatternOffsetY((imageObj.height - zone.sizeY) / 2);
    element.draw();
  };
  imageObj.src = this.utils.getImgUrl(filename, 'configurator_zone');
```

I found a solution this afternoon. 
In order to reproduce the problem, the edge of the image must be in contact with the cross. By reducing the size of the cross compared to the size of the image, the problem disappears.

Problematic cross : [cross reproducing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1dHR.png)

Correct cross : [correct cross](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2g7a.png)

Comment: Hi Vinecent - it looks like either you have found a bug in Konva OR there is an issue in your code. Please could you post a minimal example as described here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - we can then replicate what you see and determine the cause and suggest solutions.